# Como mudar a versão do Jquery no wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugin-wordpress, php-7.4

Estou fazendo a manutenção de um plugin que utiliza a versão 1.4.1 do Jquery e roda na versão 5.2 do Wordpess

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
```

E o Wordpress 5.6 o mais atual utiliza a versão 3.3.2 do jquery .

```
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.3.2
```

Como eu posso mudar da versão 3.3.2 para a 1.4.1 no Wordpress 5.6?

Obs: Quero mudar a versão para ver se o plugin está quebrando na versão 5.6 por causa do Jquery .

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o plugin [jQuery Manager for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-manager/), que deixa você escolher entre várias versões do jQuery

Answer (score 0):

O melhor nesse caso seria mesmo utilizar o plugin **jQuery Manager for Wordpress** como já sugerido. As vantagens desse plugin são:

- Você pode escolher uma versão específica do jQuery; Ativar ou desativar a qualquer momento com um clique;
- E só é executado no front-end do seu site, ele não interfere no core do Wordpress.
- Além de ser open source, ou seja, você pode contribuir para melhorá-lo.

Lembre-se de sempre manter um backup do seu site caso ocorra um problema.